# Dynamically merge arrays using object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, matching

I have the following arrays:

```
var scores = [
  { user: "Bob", score: 19 }, 
  { user: "Harry", score: 27 }, 
  { user: "Janelle", score: 35 }
]

var ranks = [
  { name: "Bob", rank: 3 }, 
  { name: "Harry", rank: 2 }, 
  { name: "Janelle", rank: 1 }
]
```

How can I merge the two arrays and return an array like:

```
var merged = [
  { name: "Bob", rank: 3, score: 19  }, 
  { name: "Harry", rank: 2, score: 27  }, 
  { name: "Janelle", rank: 1, score: 35  }
]
```

Matching `scores` to the corresponding names from the first array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with [spread syntax](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread) as the following:

```js
const scores = [
  { user: "Bob", score: 19 }, 
  { user: "Harry", score: 27 }, 
  { user: "Janelle", score: 35 }
];

const ranks = [
  { name: "Bob", rank: 3 }, 
  { name: "Harry", rank: 2 }, 
  { name: "Janelle", rank: 1 }
];

const result = scores.map(e => ({...e, rank: ranks.find(r => r.name === e.user).rank}));

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!